# How ignore actions name in route with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Let's say I have following simple controller:

```
public class DataController: Controller
{     
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Now I'd like `Index` action to be allways called if there is a GET request to DataContoller. I other words to ignore action name and any other parameters. For example all of following calls should be handled by `Index` action:

- https://localhost:5000/data
- https://localhost:5000/data/anything
- https://localhost:5000/data/anything/secondAnything
- https://localhost:5000/data/anything?someParameter=3

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You should update your `RouteConfig` like so:

```cs
public class RouteConfig
{
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "RouteOverwrite",
                url: "data/{*catchall}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Data", action = "Index" }
            );
        }
}
```

Make sure you use this in `Application_Start`:

```cs
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

// register route config
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's would be the difference using {catchall} instead of {*catchall} in this case?

Comment: @MaximeMatter I honestly can't recall.. I believe without the asterisk ASP.NET will try to parse it in as a parameter or something wonky like that. I do know that if you reference a named placeholder (i.e. `{someVal}`), and then have a route method with `someVal` as a parameter, it will parse the `{someVal}` part of the route out and fill in the parameter with that.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using routetable. check out system.web.routing in asp.net mvc.